# While loop with if statement plus result of variable

Tags: bash

I was doing a script for myself to summarize commands I use daily in one handy script. So basically I ended doing it with a conditional checking if the .git folder exists first but I'd like to make it more interesting and like so understand better the loop. My desire is to have a variable like:

"output=$(git status)" and if the result is 0, continue depending on the statement. If the result is other than 0, break the loop and end the script with a message like "the actual directory hasn't a .git repo".

I let you my first idea of it but without the git status as I don't know how to add it neither where to. Thank you guys!

```
set -e 

gitrepo=true

while [ $gitrepo == true ]; do
  if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
     echo "not a git directory"
     $gitrepo=false
  else

  read -p "Commit message: " commit

  git commit -am "$commit"
  fi  
done
```

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : Isn't `$?` at that point guaranteed to be true? After all, the most recently executed statement was  `[ $gitrepo == true ]`, and this must have set the exit code to 0 (otherwise the loop would not have been entered). IMO, we have simply a non-terminating loop.

Comment: @user1934428 - yes, my bad, you will have `$?` as `0` from `[ $gitrepo = true ]` Your loop is non-terminating because `$gitrepo=false` fall within `if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]` which will never test false unless `gitrepo` changes (a chicken and the egg case `:)`

Comment: But guys, I'd like to implement a "git status" also inside of the loop and so in case git status returns the common answer "Fatal: Not a git repository" exit with a "Not a git directory, check the path". So in case if git status returns a non zero status code, then it exits with a not a git directory. But this, obliges me to run first git status and then the script which it has no sense as the script has to do everything itself (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I did as Cyrus suggested:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e 

gitrepo=True

while [[ $gitrepo ]]; do

  if [[ ! $? ]]; then
      echo "not a git directory"
      gitrepo=False
  else
      read -p "Commit message: " -r commit
      git commit -am "$commit"
      exit 0
  fi  

done
```